# Best practices for wiring a boathouse - wiring

Tags: electrical

This is related to this: [Best practices for wiring boathouse - within the boathouse](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/281173/best-practices-for-wiring-boathouse-within-the-boathouse)

What are the best recommendations for wiring within a boathouse near saltwater? Specifically, for securing wires to joist and for boxes and outlets that will survive long in a saltwater mist environment?

Answer (score 1):

Plastic conduit and THWN or XHHW wires inside the conduit. Either flexible liquidtight or glued Schedule 40/80 PVC.

Plastic "weatherproof" boxes with "in use" covers - basicially consider it to be "outside" as far as receptacles and switches are concerned, and given saltwater, plastic boxes are less subject to corrosion than metal ones are.